# Flutter adding close icon to PopupMenuButton

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter PopupMenuButton and want to add one close icon above top right corner of first popupmenuitem. I have the sample code below. It would be great if someone help on this.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  onSelected: (value) {
    // your logic
  },
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext bc) {
    return const [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("Hello"),
        value: '/hello',
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("About"),
        value: '/about',
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("Contact"),
        value: '/contact',
      )
    ];
  },
)
```

Comment: have you tried using a dialog?

Comment: @Don, Actually we want to add popup button

Comment: If you click the popupMenuItem, your PopupMenuButton close.
I don't understand your question. already flutter implement close feature in PopupMenuItem